# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I am using simple length function to check length greater than zero based on id. Code i am using is

```
if ($('#abcd').length > 0)
{
    var abcd = $('#abcd').val();
}
```

This code is working fine and producing no error. But if i am using simple javascript in this way

```
if (document.getElementById('abcd').length > 0)
{
    var abcd = document.getElementById('abcd').val();
}
```

Then it is not working and producing this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null". What does this error mean and how can i get this working ?

Answer (score 4):

If the element is not there then [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) method would return `null` and you are trying to get it's `length` property, which is throwing the exception. Instead simply check it's defined or not in the if condition.

```
if (document.getElementById('abcd'))
```

---

Use a variable instead of getting element twice. Although there is no [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method for DOM element which is a jQuery method, instead use [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) property to get value.

```
var ele = document.getElementById('abcd');

if (ele){
    var abcd = ele.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because there will be not elements in `id ="abcd"`,

So try this;

```
if (document.getElementById('abcd')){
 var abcd = document.getElementById('abcd').val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.Get value of field then use length to for comparison.

```
if ($('#abcd').val().length > 0)
{
    var abcd = $('#abcd').val();
}
```

```js
if ($('#abcd').val().length > 0)
{
    var abcd = $('#abcd').val();
    console.log(abcd);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="abcd"  value="hello">
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work..

```
if (document.getElementById('myElementId') === null){
 alert('Does not exist!');
}else{
 alert('Exist!');
}
```